# Data Racing in Reading form openMP shared memory

Tags: c++, openmp, shared-memory

I understand that in openMP programming data writing to shared variables needs specific rituals to prevent data racing conditions. But is a racing condition possible to happen in a purely reading from a variable scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While concurrent reading of memory locations is safe, concurrent reading from a data structure in general may lead to races, if reading updates some internal state. Two examples are splay trees (which do self-adjustment on read), and data structures that keep internal statistics for reads.

Answer (score 0):

In a purely reading scenario it is impossible to have a race condition. Race conditions only occur in reads when there are writes because it is no determinism in what you will read (it could be the old value that you read or the newly written one).

Comment: Thanks. So you mean that if I share an enormous C++ vector container (a few GIGs) among threads it should be safe for them to read from it? What about the program's efficiency?

Comment: Your bottleneck here is memory transfer from RAM to CPU cache, or even worse, from hard drive to RAM to CPU cache. What are you trying to do with the data, just read it?

Comment: This involves analysis of brain MRI images and I know that a RAM > 12Gig is mandatory. Yes a part of pipeline involves reading a container which is a wrapper around std:vector. Also in the pipeline I should manipulate(R/W acess) another vector but that is a different container. What is a cache-friendly approach for this?

Comment: Find a block size of the std::vector that would fit in cache.  Iterate over blocks (single boss thread).  Within each block split over child threads?

Comment: Can this be done with the GPU as certain GPUS have high memory throughputs and can do vector manipulation extremely well? Outside of that do what emsr said after you have implemented your code and run it through valgrind and viewed the results in kcachegrind. See which loop you need to optimize first before you do anything.

Comment: Dear emsr threads may need access to a particular (random) iteration of the vector depending on their previous analysis, so do I get it correcly that your strategy only can linearly distribute the date among threads?

Comment: Dear Jason I am not aware how to interact with GPU in linux OS and GCC. Could you introduce any material?

Comment: @Sourena Look into OpenGL (works with all GPUS) or CUDA (limited to nvidia gpus). I have only worked with CUDA and I usually just include a header file and compile using the nvcc compiler. I recommend CUDA by Example by Jason Sanders and Edward Kandrot.